# XAMPP Error with using ErrorDocument in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp, http-status-code-404, errordocument

I am using a .htaccess file for a short url system that I made. It is supposed to use a file, sudir.php, to find the url that the "code" that was entered is for. But whenever I goto the page at `http://localhost/shorturl/t10m3S` which doesn't exist so it is supposed to redirect with sudir.php, but it only takes me to a generic "Not Found" page.

This is what i have in my `.htaccess`:

> ErrorDocument 404 /shorturl/sudir.php

If I change it to my `phptesting` folder, it shows the index of that folder. If I change it to just the `shorturl` folder, it still gives me the generic 404 error page. If I remove it completely it shows the default page from Apache. So it basically seems like Apache or `.htaccess` or something doesn't know that the `shorturl` folder exists even though I can access it and it works. It seems all I need is for it to acknowledge that the folder is there and actually load the `sudir.php` file, but I don't know what to do.

Additional Info:
I am using a `.htaccess` file in a different directory to redirect to YouTube pages like how `youtu.be` does and it works perfectly fine. I did have the same problem with it though at first, but I just renamed the folder it was in and changed the `.htaccess` to correspond and it started working. I have tried the same with `shorturl`, but it did not work.